# “ameliorate” vs “alleviate”

Tags: meaning, differences

The meanings for [*ameliorate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ameliorate) and [*alleviate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alleviate) are quite similar,
but I don’t think they are exact synonyms: what are the nuances behind choosing which one to use in a particular context?

I’d like some example sentences to show where one of them ***can’t*** be substituted by the other.

Comment: There are no -exact- synonyms. Except maybe in math. A pail is a bucket, but they have different connotations and collocations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The American Heritage Dictionary*, 4th Edition, defines *ameliorate* as: to make better; improve. Under their entry for *improve*, there is this note about synonyms:

> *improve, better, help, ameliorate*: These verbs mean to advance to a more desirable, valuable, or excellent state. *Improve* and *better*, the most general terms, are often interchangeable: *You can improve* (or *better*) *your mind through study; I got a haircut to improve* (or *better*) *my appearance. Help* usually implies limited relief or change: *Gargling helps a sore throat.* To ***ameliorate*** is to improve circumstances that demand change: *Volunteers were able to ameliorate conditions in the refugee camp.*

*Alleviate* is defined by *The American Heritage Dictionary* as: to make (pain, for example) more bearable. Under their entry for *relieve*, there is this note about synonyms:

> *relieve, allay, alleviate, assuage, lighten, mitigate, palliate*: These verbs mean to make something less severe or more bearable. To *relieve* is to make more endurable something causing discomfort or distress: *"that misery which he strives in vain to relieve"* ... ***Alleviate*** connotes temporary lessening of distress without removal of its cause: *"No arguments shall be wanting on my part that can alleviate so severe a misfortune.* (Jane Austen)...

In medical writing, *ameliorate* is used when describing a patient's condition. *Alleviate* is used when lessening pain. So you could say, for example, "The patient's condition was ameliorated when we administered pain medicine to alleviate her headache." That is, you improved the situation by relieving the pain.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't really that similar at all.

Alleviate is a word to use to say that something will fix or nearly fix (or at least somewhat help fix) a problem.

Ameliorate is a word to use to say that something won't really fix the problem, but will make the impact of it less bad. Sort of cushioning the blow.

Answer (score 1):

Alleviate is most commonly used to describe pain reduction, whereas ameliorate seems to be used for more abstract 'pain', for example 'ameliorate the effects of recession.'

As @T.E.D. says - the first does something, whereas the second reduces the effects of something.

Comment: Is your “Alleviate is ... whereas alleviate seems” contrast intended?  Also “used do describe” is a typo.

Comment: Need to avoid answering questions from my smartphone - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You’re right that these are quite similar.  Per the OED, ***alleviate*** is

> To lighten, or render more tolerable, or endurable; to relieve, mitigate

While in (non-)contrast, ***ameliorate*** is

> To make better; to better, improve.

There is also an intransitive sense for *ameliorate*, where it means “to grow better” rather than “to make better”.

I may be wrong, but my instinct of contemporary usage is that one is more apt to employ *alleviate* when the problem is completely resolved, and *ameliorate* when it is improved but not necessarily removed altogether.

Since the two words can in fact, or at least in theory, be used interchangeable, it is probably best not to assume anything, and to spell out just what you mean if there is any question.

Here are some OED citations for *ameliorate*:

> - 1813 Sir H. Davy *Agric. Chem.* 203 ― A sterile soil··may be ameliorated by the application of quick lime.
> - 1849 Macaulay *Hist. Eng.* I. 279 ― In every human being there is a wish to ameliorate his own condition.
> - 1882 Geikie in *Macm. Mag.* Mar. 365/2 ― [Man]··would find his way back as the climate ameliorated.

And here are some for *alleviate*:

> - 1712 Steele *Spect.* No. 450 ⁋3, ― I··found means to alleviate, and at last conquer my Affliction.
> - 1871 Napheys *Prevent. Dis.* ɪɪɪ. ii. 619 ― To alleviate the sufferings of the invalid.
> - 1876 Mozley *Univ. Serm.* ᴠ. 120 ― Hope alleviates the sorrow of that home.

If you are looking for a fine distinction, there is something ***“uplifting”*** about  *alleviate* that does not quite occur in *ameliorate*, which is simply to improve.

Comment: *The American Heritage Dictionary*'s note about synonyms says almost the opposite: "*alleviate* connotes temporary lessening of distress without removal of its cause."

Answer (score 1):

The term **ameliorate** [derives](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=amelioration&allowed_in_frame=0) from Latin, *melior* "better".

Alleviate also [derives](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=alleviate&searchmode=none) from Latin, *ad- "to" (see ad-) + levis "light" in weight (see lever)*.

The root, *lever* [means](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lever&allowed_in_frame=0) *to raise*.

There is a great deal of overlap in these closely related words.  However, they are not identical in meaining. **Ameliorate**, in *making better* often focuses on the good aspects.  **Alleviate** tends to focus on the bad things that have to be *made lighter or lifted*.

A search of Google for *ameliorate examples* provides

> A consistent routine of exercise has shown to **ameliorate** health.
>
> I wish there was a way to **ameliorate** this whole bathing process; anything would be better than this!
>
> Another approach would be to use short-term fixes to **ameliorate** the current situation while unwinding the euro.
>
> They get opportunities to recognize and **ameliorate** bad choices.
>
> Access to clean water would **ameliorate** living conditions within the
> village.

In none of these sentences would **alleviate** be appropriate.  Needless to say, there are many other examples from that search where the terms wholly overlap and **aleviate** could be substituted.

It is my impression that, in the vast majority of cases, the obverse would not be true. **Ameliorate** can nearly always be substituted for **alleviate**.

Answer (score 0):

While I struggle to come up with a situation where one would be considered incorrect in place of another, I certain that there are particular contexts in which one word is **stronger** than the other in terms of feel. Also etymologically speaking, ameliorate comes is associated with "making better" while alleviate is associated with "lifting" or "lightening", as in a load.

Consider this:

If one is sick, you my say that medicine is used to alleviate the sickness.
Meanwhile, a sound-minded politician might be on a mission to *ameliorate* poverty in the U.S.

Alleviate *leans closer to* the definition/feel of "relieve" which has a different, less progressive or forward moving feeling than the word *ameliorate*, which is progressive, more active.

Answer (score -1):

It's really very simple.  As all the wonderful examples posted clearly show:

Ameliorate: To improve or make better.
Thus: This game could be improved by adding some more colour." becomes "This game could be ameliorated by adding some colour".

Alleviate is temporary, i.e. it removes the symptom but not the cause.

The game is not a symptom ergo alleviate would not fit.
Perhaps, "My boredom with this game could be alleviated with some beer and friends."
Boredom being a symptom of the game's lack of colour.