# What is it called when you take a word with a bad connotation and make it a word with a positive connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

Take the word "nice" as an example. Before it was used negatively and today when something is *nice*, it is good. How is this called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the origins of the word "nice"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31368/what-are-the-origins-of-the-word-nice) - "What's it called when a word with bad connotations develops a positive meaning?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for "making something more tolerable?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198157/word-for-making-something-more-tolerable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One term is **melioration**

> Historical Linguistics. semantic change in a word to a more approved
> or more respectable meaning.
> https://www.dictionary.com/browse/melioration

Comment: [That's the word!](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/535259/365490).

Comment: Hmm, I've heard _amelioration_ before. I wonder what the difference is.